# What happened when kfree function called

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, heap-memory, linux-device-driver

I am testing kernel module that allocates memory using `kmalloc` to some variable and `memset` it's value and `free`.
Here is the code with zeroisation memory routine.

```
    unsigned char *a = (unsigned char *)kmalloc(256, GFP_KERNEL);
    unsigned char *b;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
       a[i]=(unsigned char)i;
    }
    // print variable a
    printk("before zeroisation\n");
    for(i=0;i<255;i++)
    {
      printk("%02x", a[i]);
    }

    // copy allocated address to variable b
    b =a;

    memset(a, 0x00, 256);
    // print memset to zero
    printk("memset variable a\n");
    for(i=0;i<255;i++)
    {
      printk("%02x", b[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    a=NULL;

    // print free variable's address
    printk("after zeroisation\n");
    for(i=0;i<255;i++)
    {
      printk("%02x", b[i]);
    }
```

and result is

```
before zeroization  
000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f ...  
memset variable a
00000000000000000000000000000000 ...  
after zeroization  
001e7f430088ffff0000000000000000 ...
```

It seems free of variable makes insert value of something's address in allocated area. 001e7f430088ffff -> ffff8800437f1e00 (in little endian)
 Additionaly address of pointer of b is ffff8800437f0800
 I know that dynamic memory allocation in heap memory has free-list made of double-linked list.
 I think this is related to memory allocation process too.

I want to know the meaning of value 001e7f430088ffff and process of within `kfree` function.
 thanks.

Comment: Accessing a freed memory is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @LPs didn't undefined behavior means result is unexpected?(if I'm understand correctly.) but this result always the same.

Comment: There are 3 types of memory allocators in the kernel: `slab`, `slub` and `slob`. With which one your kernel is configured? (CONFIG_SLAB, CONFIG_SLOB or CONFIG_SLUB).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Check out the kernel config I got CONFIG_SLUB=y

Comment: Do you always get related values in free memory and address of b?

Comment: Do you always get related values in free memory and address of b? If it is so, then make a third pointer two. and then check the result. I have got an idea who validity would depened on the experiement you perform.

Comment: @Mazhar address of b and value 0x001e7f430088ffff  varies in every execution. 8-bytes of unknown variable is always inserted.

Comment: In this case these 8 bytes seems relevant. I just want you to tell me about values on other run.

Comment: It looks like an 8-byte amd64 pointer value. I assume it is a "next" pointer in a linked list of free blocks.

Comment: Undefined means that what you find there is not predictible. On the same system in a different time, with other loaded modules or whatever you can find whatever randomly. What if another module/task take that memory and write something there in the time between free and b dereference.

Comment: can you please try once to run the following  code  after disabling  SMP and use a spinlock i.e disable the preemption. that will confirm the undefined behavior whether it is effect of kfree or  kernel had allocated the memory chunk to any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
   b =a;
```

Which means both a and b points to same memory. Free any pointer will result in losing the memory from both pointers. and then this memory can contain any garbage value.

```
  free(a);
  a=NULL;
```

Once freed no need to assign `NULL`. When you free a pointer, it means it is no more pointing to any memory.

So if you need to avoid such behavior

1. Either don't free pointer `a`. Just assign it `NULL` or another memory
2. Or use `memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));` function to copy values in `a`. But before that you have to allocate memory to `b`

Comment: The asker **intentionally** dereferences `free`-ed pointer, and asks about its content. I see no reason to remind him that such dereference shouldn't be used in real programs.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right. I thought he could be new to this kind of situation. So if if it won't help, I will remove it.